# In which folder enabled desktop slideshow images are stored in windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, slideshow, desktop-wallpaper

As we know that in 
`Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Desktop Background` 
 multiple desktop background images are available. From there we can select some of them for slideshow and we can set interval also. I have selected few images .
Now I have to find out in which folder **enabled desktop slideshow images** are present in windows 7.

When I say **enabled** that means images I have selected out of total available images.

Solutions I have tried :

`C:\\windows\\web`
This folder contains **all images** available for the slideshow. I want images which are **enabled**.

`C:\\users\\Username\\Appdata\\local\\microsoft\\windows\\Themes`
There no images in that folder also **custom.theme** does not contain any path.

`C:\\Windows\\Resources\\Themes`
Nothing is there.

If you can tell me registry or folder or path of images inside any file , anything it will be good .

Answer (score 1):

I found mine in:

PC > Local Disk (C:) > Users > [YOUR USERNAME] > AppData > Local > Packages > Microsoft

Have you tried that one? normally this path is hidden.

Also you can try in:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Lock ScreenCreative

I hope it works for you.

Regards.